# GTM & Cross-domain tracking: do I need to set it up in all tags that fire on second domain?

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-tag-manager

I have SiteA and SiteB.
SiteB is an ecommerce platform of let's say 5 pages (page1, page2, etc.), this means that page1 on SiteB is always the only landing page when users jumps from SiteA to SiteB.
Do I need to set the cross-domain tracking up on SiteB on all pages? Or can I do that on page1 only?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google Analytics Settings variable in GTM, configure cross-domain tracking there and reference the variable in all of your GA tags. This will ensure your cross-domain tracking is set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can set cross-domain tracking only for 1 page on Site B. Actually cross-domain linking happens at the moment of transition from Site A to Site B via Page View tag. Like a bridge. Cross-domain setting automatically decorates links on Site A to Site B with parameter `ClientID` and tracker on Site B accept this parameter. Next actions on Site B will be in the same session and no matter there is a cross-domain setting on other tags or not.